# Find addition of second field of each array

Tags: node.js

```
var x = { 'a' : [1,2], 'b' : [3,4]}
```

In this object, I want to calculate the addition of second positioned value of each key in object.

Comment: did below answer solve your issue?

Comment: `console.log(x.a[1] + x.b[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```js
    var x = { 'a' : [1,2], 'b' : [3,4]} 
    var secondKey = Object.keys(x)[1]; //fetched the key at second index
    var sum = x[secondKey].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    console.log(sum)
```

Hope this helps.